# Oracle Apex Mail not sending from particular email address, why?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I've created a Apex mail.send email and it works when the email is from a gmail account, however, when the email is from  a work one xxxx.xxxx@techstore.com then it does not send, i'm not sure why. How would you suggest I resolve this? Thank you all.

```
APEX_MAIL.SEND(
    p_to        => email,
        p_from      => 'xxxx.xxxx@techstore.com',
        p_subj      => 'No Reply',
        p_body      => l_body_html,
        p_body_html => l_body_html);
```

xxx.xxx is an actual name, I just replaced it with x for the purpose of sharing on this site.

Comment: Can you show the code snippet used to send the email?

Comment: Hi, @learningloop the code is now in the above edit.

Comment: first step: query apex_mail_log from within SQL Workshop and look for errors. This may also be found in Monitor Activity.

Comment: Agreed with Scott. Problems with emails can occur at both the sending and the receiving ends - so you need to determine whether the email was successfully sent or not; if it was sent successfully, you can then look at why it wasn't delivered (e.g. maybe it is not getting past the spam filter).

Answer (score 0):

You missed this

```
apex_mail.push_queue;
```

After done, you can check the status with the query below

```
select * from APEX_MAIL_QUEUE;
```